# Struct with one member or just typedef

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

While im coding I declare structs or classes because they are based on real world objects/ideas/concepts.

But often those structs/classes only have one single member. So I was wondering if it makes any difference, if I simpy make a typedef.

And then I'm not sure if that's correct, because typedefs are not 'objects' in my opinion.

So should I do:

```
struct Y { int x; }
```

or just:

```
typedef int Y;
```

Does it make any difference? Is my image of structs being objects and typedefs being something else correct?

Comment: "Does it make any difference?" they are different.  Whether it makes any difference in your program depends **entirely** on what you intend to do.  You're showing 2 solutions to an undescribed problem.

Comment: Also a third option `using Y = int;`

Comment: There is a huge difference. The first introduces an entirely new type, the second not. Eg .:you can pass the 'typedef Y' to a function expecting an integer (in this case), but not the 'struct Y'

Comment: As an example where there is a major difference, certain standard library specializations are only supported for user-defined types. For example, you can legally specialize `std::hash<Y>`  for your own nefarious purposes where `Y` is your struct. You can't do the same when `Y` is an trivial alias to `int` (if I remember 17.6.4.2.1 with any accuracy, I'm sure i'll be corrected if I didn't).

Answer (score 4):

There's a huge difference. With the typedef all the following are valid:

```
Y y = 14.3;
y += 7;
y = 1 + y << 3;
std::cout << y;
double d = y;
```

With the struct none are, unless you choose to expose those operations. The question is, do you have something that is an `int`, with no restrictions, or an abstraction that is in some way based on an integer value, and has its own constraints or invariant?

Answer (score 1):

There are several aspects you should take into consideration:

---

### **Primitive types operations**

**typedef**, unlike **struct/class**, is just another name for the type, an alias.
Therfore, if you choose to use a **typedef** for a primitive, you'll be able to perform all the primitive types operations  (like addition, subtraction and so on):

```
Y y = 4;
y+=5;
printf("Y is %d", y);
```

On the opposite, if you choose to use **struct/class** you will lose all this functionality and you'll have to implement these operators yourself.

---

### Maintainability and extensibility

Primitive types, unlike structs can neither be complemented nor inherited.
Therefore, if you plan to inherit from your type, or complement it with additional fields, you should prefer **class** over **typedef**.

```
class X : public Y { int x; }
```

---

### Using typeid

As I mentioned, **typedef** is an alias for the type.
Therefore, if you want your type to get a different id than the primitive type, you definitely should choose **struct/class**:

```
typedef int Y;
typeid(Y)==typeid(int)
```

In this case the expression will be true.

```
struct Y { int x; }
typeid(Y)==typeid(int)
```

In this case the expression will be false.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it does not really matter one way or the other.  Where it does matter is if you need to overload a function based on `Y` parameters, or if you want to add custom methods to (or override operators on) `Y`.  A `typedef` is just an alias, so `typedef int Y` is just a normal `int` as far as the compiler is concerned, whereas `struct Y` is its own distinct type.